# Does anyone know of any open source availability / scheduling systems?

Tags: php, sql, open-source, scheduling

I'm trying to make an availability / scheduling system... Basically, I want users to be able to log into this system, and show that they're available during a certain time block, then I want another user to be able to log in and see who's available and when, and to be able to book someones time (so they no longer show up as available). I want to use PHP and SQL. Does anyone know if there are any open source systems out there that do something similar? I feel like there would be and it would be silly to rebuild one from scratch.

Although I want to use PHP and SQL, I'll consider any other open source tools that don't use those technologies, but obviously php and sql are preferred. 
Thanks

**EDIT**: I know this problem can be solved with google calendar... but I need to find another way other than google calendar.

Comment: I've found phpScheduleIt... anyone know of any other ones out there? phpScheduleIt doesn't seem to have that friendly of an interface.

Comment: The company I work for recently went through this, being as the IT manager loves 3rd party software and all.. needless to say I ended up developing a custom solution. It took about 2 weeks(bugs, features being added and all) - I'd suggest giving it a shot.

Comment: http://calendar.google.com

Comment: @Dalton I thought about making a custom solutions, but I don't know if ive figured out all the logic behind it yet, so I was looking for an open source that I can customize instead. I'm just not too sure how to store time intervals into the database and then if the time is booked separate those time intervals and so on.

Comment: @Phil Unix timestamps work wonders :)

Comment: @Dalton Conley criky and how!

Comment: @Phil let me know which one I should give the bounty to, otherwise it will automatically assign the bounty.

Comment: Keng, I'm not sure haha. maybe the first one by Hoang Long, it looks pretty good and has the most votes. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this open source project. You can check this: http://supercali.inforest.com/

*SuperCali is an event calendar script that supports nested categories of events and multiple moderators, making it a good choice for organizations managing a large number of activities. SuperCali is designed to make data entry as easy and error-free as possible as well as provide a flexible, modular framework for displaying event information. SuperCali works with PHP and MySQL and is free, "open source" software released under the GNU General Public License.*

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm going to go a little outside the box here and ask if you've considered Gmail's calendar app?  It has apis but I think you can skip that and just have the user's share their calendars and they can see them all together in one view.

This has the benefits of taking care of the security for you the advanced scheduling for you.

I know it's not what you're asking for but if you're just wanting the scheduling without the security headaches and coding necessary to bring it up and online, maybe this will work.

Comment: Yea, I'm using google calendar to share calendars, but currently that's only used for meetings and that kind of thing, if there are no meetings for you, you have nothing on your calendar, but your time still may be "booked" where you're working on a project

Comment: @Phil - Then you can create new calendars for projects, and share them with project members.  It will still show on their calendars that way...

Comment: @Phil - If it's for a business, you can adminstrate it all through Google Apps. It's relatively inexpensive and can also be your email platform, etc.

Comment: Yea... Google Calendar isn't an option. I know it would work, but I need to find something else.

Comment: @Phil ....hmmmm....ok. can you put a bounty on this question? I will do it myself if you aren't able to. Seems a good enough question to me...oops...it needs another day to age before you can put a bounty on it.

Comment: @Keng... if you could put a bounty on this question that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[mrbs](http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/)? Any ical server?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://phpicalendar.net/ as a decent ICalendar client.  This makes basically any ICalendar server viable.

More specific to scheduling, there is an open source project using php and mysql called phpMyCal at http://dev.neb.net/phpMyCal/

Answer (score 1):

We do this with MRBS http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/ and it meets your specifications of php/mysql- while it sounds like a room booking system, it is for reserving anything.  It is very flexible, uses many different authentication systems, and if I can install it (with help from the user forums), probably anyone can.